# c# Equivalent of Err in vb

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

Let me know: how can I access Err in C#? This is sample VB Code to convert:

```
If Len(sPart1) <> PART1_LENGTH Then
    Err.Raise(vbObjectError,  , "Part 1 must be " & PART1_LENGTH)

ElseIf Not IsNumeric(sPart1) Then 
    Err.Raise(vbObjectError,  , "Part 1 must be numeric")
```

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got d info you want...

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of

```
  throw new Exception();
```

You take ref. from MSDN : [Error Raising and Handling Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ey5ey87%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you were asking about syntax, not specific classes:

```
throw new SomeException("text");
```

Answer (score 2):

First, let's translate that to modern VB code:

```
If sPart1.Length <> PART1_LENGTH Then
  Throw New ApplicationException("Part 1 must be " & PART1_LENGTH)
ElseIf Not IsNumeric(sPart1) Then
  Throw New ApplicationException("Part 1 must be numeric")
End If
```

Then the C# translation is straight forward:

```
int part;
if (sPart1.Length != PART1_LENGTH) {
  throw new ApplicationException("Part 1 must be " + PART1_LENGTH.ToString());
} else if (!Int32.TryParse(sPart1, out part)) {
  throw new ApplicationException("Part 1 must be numeric")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Err.Raise` with

```
  throw new Exception("Part 1 must be numeric");
```

Comment: There is more to it than just 'use exceptions'. The original error handing crap from vb6 should not be relied upon in .NET. Learn exceptions, learn stacktraces.

Answer (score 0):

I know exceptions should be used in both C# and VB.NET, but for posterity, it is possible to use the ErrObject in C#.

Complete sample program of OP's program converted to C#:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace ErrSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ErrObject err = Information.Err();

            // Definitions
            const int PART1_LENGTH = 5;
            string sPart1 = "Some value";
            int vbObjectError = 123;
            double d;

            if (sPart1.Length != PART1_LENGTH)
                err.Raise(vbObjectError, null, "Part 1 must be " + PART1_LENGTH);
            else if (!double.TryParse(sPart1, out d))
                err.Raise(vbObjectError, null, "Part 1 must be numeric");
        }
    }
}
```